# Return get_header and get_footer string instead of echo it

Tags: templates, headers, footer

I am trying to use mustache within a wordpress application and modularize it. I would like to use mustache partials to inject the header and footer string into individual template files.

However, as soon as I call get_header / get_footer on the controller layer, the header and footer are echo'ed out immediately. What I am trying to do is just retrieve the markup from the header and footer and store it into a variable, for 'later' injection into the template is this possible?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: theses functions don't use filters. then to custom header and footer, you can create your own functions in your theme.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an output buffer!

```
ob_start();
get_header();
$header = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

The header is now in `$header` and you can do with it as you please.